# Getting string from list<t>

Tags: c#

I am looking at better way of writing following code using linq/lambda expression..

I am trying to form a string from list. I have function that convert t to string. So what i want is have a string from list.

Here is pseudo code:

```
  string strTemp;

  foreach (SearchTerm s in terms)
  {
    strTemp +=  string.Format(" and {0} ", s.CreateToString());
  }
```

where terms is list<searchTerms>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
string temp = String.Join(" and ", terms.Select(s => s.CreateString()));
```

If you're not using .Net 4.0, you'll need to add `.ToArray()`.

If you're calling the `ToString` method on each `term` (as opposed to a different method) and you are using .Net 4.0, you can simply write

```
string temp = String.Join(" and ", terms);
```

Comment: ...could you elaborate on why this is different with .Net 4.0? Is the `Join(...)` signature changed?

Comment: @Peter: .Net 4.0 adds [three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) that take [`IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx), [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx), and `object[]`.

Comment: Earlier versions only took a `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method I wrote to take an `IEnumerable<T>` and a string to use as a delimiter, and it returns the delimited string.  Using this, you should be able to achieve what you want by calling `terms.ToDelimitedString(" and ");`

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, string delimiter)
{
    // ensure that our list has at least 1 entry
    if (list == null || !list.Any())
        return String.Empty;

    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    TSource lastItemSeen = default(TSource);
    bool isFirstIteration = true;

    // enumerate through the list, "lagging" the appending by 1 entry.
    //  This avoids the need to strip away an extra trailing delimiter
    foreach (TSource item in list)
    {
        // null values should be skipped
        if (!isFirstIteration && lastItemSeen != null)
            returnString.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", lastItemSeen, delimiter);
        lastItemSeen = item;
        isFirstIteration = false;
    }

    // tack on the remaining list entry and return the string
    return returnString.Append(lastItemSeen).ToString();
}
```

Comment: ... what is the value added for this code vs String.Join or IEnumerable<string>.Aggregate?  This is a lot of code, but I don't get why you would write it?

Comment: @Brian: Until .Net 4.0, String.Join only took a `string[]`.  Using the `Aggregate` extension method will either be slower or far messier.  I've written a similar extension method myself in several answers here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224012/can-all-for-loops-be-replaced-with-a-linq-statement/2224034#2224034

Comment: So?  You have way too much code there.  You are re-inventing the wheel:  `string.Join(" and ", terms.Select(term => term.ToString()).ToArray());`.  Even if you use Aggregate with a StringBuilder in the lambda, it is MUCH cleaner to do it that way.  If you want the extension method, that is great (and I perfer it over directly calling Aggregate or string.Join), but to implement in this way is ugly and bug-prone.

Comment: @Brian: Don't call `ToArray()` if you can avoid it.  It will be inefficient for large lists.

Comment: @SLaks: If you can quantitatively show me that it is noticeably slower with your data set, then I would agree.  Almost always, ToArray() is negligible, and preferable over hard to read/maintain code.  If ToArray() really is a problem, then use Aggregate with a StringBuilder.  I fear that advice like "Don't call `ToArray()` if you can avoid it" is just pre-optimization in most cases, therefore I think it is incomplete advice.

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks has a great answer.  Just for completeness, since you asked for the "linq/lambda" way to do it:

```
var strTemp = 
  terms
  .Select(s => s.CreateString())
  .Aggregate("", (result, term) => result + term);
```